# How to manually configure TeXstudio for Windows in the CTAN package "ProTeXt-3.1.4-020114.exe"?

Tags: miktex, installing, texstudio, protext

I just downloaded MiKTeX and TeXstudio from CTAN as a zip file ProTeXt-3.1.4-020114.exe

I then installed MiKTeX and TeXstudio.

But the TeXstudio can not compile/build/view after I created/save a file.

It seems to me that the configuration has not been set up properly.

What is the standard pdfLatex that I should use in MiKTeX/bin for compile and build in TeXstudio?

What is the (MiKTeX?) internal viewer that I should use for "view" in TeXstudio?

EDIT: I happened to have installed TeXstudio first.  Then I installed MiKTeX. After I found out that TeXstudio compile/buid/view do not work, I uninstalled TeXstudio and reinstalled TeXstudio.  But it still does work.

EDIT: It turned out that the problem is MiKTeX 2.9 installation. The log file said that "regsvr32 MiKTeX209-core.dll" failed when launched from mpm.exe.  I did it manually and TeXstudio worked fine now.

Comment: Did you install MiKTeX first then TeXStudio?

Answer (score 14):

You can delete `%APPDATA%\texstudio\texstudio.ini` (while TeXstudio is not running). At the next startup, TeXstudio will use the default settings and try to detect an existing MikTeX installation as part of this.

Answer (score 0):

1. close TeXstudio
2. if deleting `%APPDATA%\texstudio\texstudio.ini` does not work
3. then delete everything in `%APPDATA%\texstudio` and
4. restart TeXstudio.

I hope this would work.